# R: Expand an S3 method defined in another package

Tags: r, methods, extension-methods

Let's say that package **A** defines and documents `foo()` and implements it for `bar1` objects.

In a new package **B**, I would like to expand this method and add its support for `bar2` objects.

Currently, I start by *reexporting* the method:

```
#' @rdname foo
#' @importFrom A foo
#' @export
A::foo
```

And then went on extending its behaviour:

```
#' @rdname foo
#' @method foo bar2
#' @export
foo.bar2 <- function(x, newparam = 3.14, ...){
  dosomething(x, newparam)
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems like this creates a conflict upon devtools checking, which returns the following warning:

```
> checking Rd metadata ... WARNING
  Rd files with duplicated name 'reexports':
    'foo.Rd'
  Rd files with duplicated alias 'reexports':
    'foo.Rd'
```

Thus, I wonder what this the best way of expanding a method without creating conflict in definition or documentation? Can I do this without having to *Depend* on the package A? Thanks!

Comment: what if you don't have the `@rdname foo` tag on the `foo.bar2` method?

Comment: Seems like the warning message doesn't change :/

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you get it working in the end?

Comment: Yes, re-exporting without its documentation them seems to have done the trick: https://github.com/easystats/parameters/blob/b70b584e77f09d479aed0b030392a43ac15d6bac/R/ci.R#L72