# How to extend the documentation of a package's S3 method?

Tags: roxygen2, code-documentation, r-s3

In my package, I'm extending an S3 method `as_bar` from the package `pcp_pack`, as applied on an object `foo` from my package `foo_pack`.

The ROxygen2 documentation is the following:

```
#' Implementation of as_bar for foo objects
#'
#' @param x same as foo_pack::as_bar
#' @param y new argument
#' @param z also new argument
#' @param ... unused, for S3 compatibility
#'
#' @name as_bar
#' @rdname as_bar
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
as_bar.foo = function(x, y, z, ...){
    #...
}
```

However, this function is quite independent and it can work without the original package. But for the function to work without having to run `library(pcp_pack)`, I had to re-export the generic method (I copied the re-exporting syntax from [dplyr `magrittr` reexport](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/1d04ef60953e12089ea0ebfad569e0d97a55fc8a/R/utils.r)), so R know that it should call a method:

```
#' @importFrom pcp_pack as_bar
#' @export
pcp_pack::as_bar
```

This works perfectly, and `as_bar` works on `foo` objects as well as on other objects.

However, the documentation is not perfect, and running `library(foo_pack);?as_bar` gives two results:

- man of `pcp_pack::as_bar`, with no mention of `as_bar.foo` in the usage
- man of `foo_pack::as_bar`, with `as_bar.foo` in the usage but nothing else

Running `library(pcp_pack)` beforehand does not change anything.

**How can I get a unified version of `?as_bar`, with all usages from all loaded packages, whichever they are?**

**EDITS**

- Related but a bit different and not answered: [Documenting generic S3 methods in R so that user can see documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630954/documenting-generic-s3-methods-in-r-so-that-user-can-see-documentation)
- Almost duplicate, without answer: [R: Expand an S3 method defined in another package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55465721/r-expand-an-s3-method-defined-in-another-package)
- If you want some context, my package is [crosstable](https://github.com/DanChaltiel/crosstable) and I want to document [`as_flextable.crosstable`](https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/207#issuecomment-614075343) from `flextable::as_flextable`.